No way to select the Region when creating a batch job
When I try to create a Batch Job from the UI, I'm not able to select a region, so I can not continue:

Not sure if it's relevant, but the image is stored in a repository in us-central1-docker.pkg.dev

The Batch API was not enable for this project. After enable it and wait few minutes, it started to show regions.
